# Limit of a spiraling sequence in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis

I did some serious mistakes while typing a question few minutes ago.

Let $z_0=(0,0)$ and $z_1=(1,0)$ and define the sequence $z_n$, for any $ n \ge 2 $, as the endpoint of a line drawn perpendicular from $z_{n-1}$ and which is half the distance of the line joining $z_{n-2}$ and $z_{n-1}$

And drawn in a rectangular spiral fashion.

E.g., $z_2=(1,1/2), z_3=(3/4,1/2)$ and so on

Clearly convergent.

But What is the limit of $z_{n}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

You can consider each coordinate separately. Look at the vectors of changes every 2 steps, so you have for $x$, for example:

$1, -1/4, 1/16, -1/64, \ldots$

which you must sum. It  is a geometric series with common factor $-1/4$ and initial value of $1$.

Similar picture will be in the $y$ direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can express the sequence of the points as a sequence of complex numbers $S_n$ in this way:
$$
(1,0) \mapsto S_0=1+0i
$$
$$
(1,0)+(0,\frac 1 2) \mapsto S_1=1+\frac 1 2 i
$$
$$
(1,0)+(0,\frac 1 2)+(-\frac 1 4,0) \mapsto S_2=1+\frac 1 2 i- \frac 1 4
$$
$$
(1,0)+(0,\frac 1 2)+(-\frac 1 4,0)+(0,-\frac 1 8) \mapsto S_3=1+\frac 1 2 i- \frac 1 4-  \frac 1 8 i
$$
$$
\cdots
$$
and the general formula for $S_n$ will be
$$
S_{n}= \sum_{k=0}^n \left( \frac i 2 \right)^k
$$
that is a geometric series with the ratio $\frac i 2 $, therefore it converges to the limit
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left( \frac i 2 \right)^k=\frac{1}{1-(i/2)}=\frac 4 5 + i \frac 2 5 
$$
Here is the plot from Mathematica:

[image]